# Laravel - Retry failed jobs on a specific queue

Tags: laravel, laravel-queue

I know that I can retry jobs that have failed in my Laravel application by using: `php artisan queue:retry 5` OR `php artisan queue:retry all` to push them back onto the queue.

What I would like to achieve though is to only retry failed jobs from a single queue. Such as `php artisan queue:retry all --queue=emails` which does not work.

I could however go through each manually by ID `php artisan queue:retry 5` but this does not help if I have 1000's of records.

So in summary, my question is, how can I retry all failed jobs on specific queue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe you can create another command

lets say

command : `php artisan example:retry_queue emails`

```
class RetryQueue extends Command
{
    protected $signature = 'example:retry_queue {queue_name?}';
    protected $description = 'Retry Queue';

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function handle()
    {
       // if the optional argument is set, then find all with match the queue name
       if ($this->argument('queue_name')) { 
            $queueList = FailedJobs::where('queue', $this->argument('queue_name'))->get();

            foreach($queueList as $list) {
                 Artisan::call('queue:retry '.$list->id);
            }
       } else {
            Artisan::call('queue:retry all');
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: If it doesn't already exist in Laravel then this is a great way to achieve it. Thanks.

Comment: I was getting The command "queue:retry 6706" does not exist. I guess calling the command like Artisan::call('queue:retry', ['id' => $list->id]); will fix that.

Comment: For some reason, I could not access the FailedJobs model in Laravel 8 so I used the DB facade instead. e.g \DB::table('failed_jobs')..

Answer (score 0):

As of Laravel 10, you can do that with a similar syntax to the one you offered. It's explained in the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queues#retrying-failed-jobs) as follows:

> You may also retry all of the failed jobs for a particular queue:
>
> ```
> php artisan queue:retry --queue=name
> ```